# Apply new patches after reversing old patches using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to patch some files in my Linux source code.For each file I'll be creating a patch(mandatory 
:single patch for each edit). Here is my repo structure.
[image]

1. patches - stores all the patches.
2. kernel_source_code - source code directory.
3. scripts - patch applying script location.

Before applying new patches I want to reverse all the patches I've applied previously.

Then begin patching from the first upto the last added file.

Eg; I add `002.patch` to directory patches/ and if `000.patch` and `001.patch` has already been applied then reverse patch using patch -p0 -R < "patch-name" (patch applying should start from 001.patch then 000.patch ). *But in the directory patches/ three scripts will be present out of them I have to select the first two 000 and 001.*

**But I find it difficult to select only the patches just before the latest patch**

Here is that portion of my script

```
echo "Going to reverse all previously applied patches "
#Reversing patches using a for loop "NEED HELP FOR SELECTING THE JUST PREVIOUS PATCHES"
for patch in `ls -lr $PATCHDIR`; do
    echo "reversing patch "  $patch
    patch -p1 -R < $PATCHDIR/$patch
    then
        echo "Reversing patch $PATCHDIR/$patch failed"
        exit 1
    fi
done

#Applying patches using a for loop
for patch in `ls $PATCHDIR`; do
    echo "Found patch file " $patch
    echo "applying patch......"
    patch -p1 < $PATCHDIR/$patch    
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        echo "Applying patch $PATCHDIR/$patch failed"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: _"But I find it difficult to select only the patches just before the **latest** patch "_ How is identified the "latest patch"? By its name? By its modification time? Are all the patches sequentially numbered?

Comment: The patches will be sequentially numbered like 000.patch , 001.patch, 002.patch and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the goal here exactly but this sounds like the sort of thing that something like [Quilt](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/quilt) was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you were expecting, but why not simply store the patch glob expansion in a Bash array? You can then walk up and down that array easily.

```
PATCHES=( $PATCHDIR/*.patch )

for ((i=${#PATCHES[@]}-2; i>=0; i--)); do
  #                    ^
  #                -2 here to skip the "last one"
  patch="${PATCHES[i]}"
  echo "reversing patch "  $patch

  # [...]

done

for patch in "${PATCHES[@]}"; do
  echo "Found patch file " $patch
  echo "applying patch......"

  # [...]

done
```

---

That being said, I think you might have two design issues here. Maybe:

1. First I don't understand why you "un-apply" all your patches to re-apply them just after that. Why not simply apply the new patch on the already parched sources? As far as I understand your patches are cumulative, or do I missed something here?
2. Given your current error handling, if some patch failed to apply/un-apply you might end up having partially patched sources your script will be unable to fix in one direction or the other.